# Gazebo 1.6.1 Bullet rolling friction, contact parameters implemented?

Tags: gazebo, contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

To which degree is `Bullet` implemented in Gazebo 1.6.1 from the [sdf description page](http://gazebosim.org/sdf/dev.html#bullet435)? I tried `<rolling_friction>` and  `<contact>` parameters and they don't work.

I also checked the [features list](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/bullet), but they are not mentioned as **TODO** or **Done**.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2403/gazebo-1.6.1-bullet-rolling-friction,-contact-parameters-implemented?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We have put Bullet integration on hold until July, 2013. The basics are in place (simple shapes, and most of the joints), but friction has not been fully tested.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0